# Image fragments when moving up and or left

Tags: java, swing

Not entirely sure how to resolve the issue as I am quite new to programming, however this seems to be my last option in terms of finding an adequate solution.

EDIT: https://streamable.com/0i92xq - video of issue

The fragmenting described occurs in the forms of horizontal and vertical gaps, horizontal when decreasing the camera's Y position, and vertical when decreasing the X, appearing and disappearing at random all over the screen.

I have read that this issue can stem from rounding errors, however in the code preview below it should be apparent that all values are kept as integers. This fragmenting only occurs when the camera is moving, so it is likely associated with the screenX and screenY variables. I am using a loop involving drawing and updating at different intervals in order to allow for a framerate slider, however this splitting doesn't seem to cause any issues as far as I can tell.

Here is the tile rendering code:

```
  public void drawLevel(Graphics graphics) {
    for (int x = 0; x < layerCount; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < worldSize; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < worldSize; z++) {
                if (level[x][y][z] != 0) {
                    int worldX = z * tileSize;
                    int worldY = y * tileSize;

                    int screenX = worldX - Player.x + screenPosition;
                    int screenY = worldY - Player.y + screenPosition;

                    if (screenX >= -tileSize && screenX < screenSize && screenY >= -tileSize && screenY < screenSize) {
                        graphics.drawImage(tileList[level[x][y][z] - 1].image, screenX, screenY, tileSize, tileSize, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you see? Questions about graphics debugging usually get better answers if they have screenshots or animated gifs illustrating the issue.

Comment: it appears to be become significantly more frequent when the fps / ups increases.
https://streamable.com/0i92xq

Comment: this is the background bleeding onto the screen - indicated by the pink